# WebView не отрабатывает скрипт локально

Tags: android, javascript, java, webview

В общем код такой.

```
    String nextAd = 
    "<html><head><style>* {margin:0;padding:0;}</style></head>"+

    "<div class=\"divcenter\">"+
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+
    "google_ad_client = \"ca-pub-2700673734435312\";"+

    "google_ad_slot = \"6365025632\";"+
    "google_ad_width = 320;"+
    "google_ad_height = 50;"+

    "</script>"+
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\""+
    "src=\"http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js\">"+
    "</script>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</html>";

    mWebView.loadData(nextAd,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

Сам ява скрипт включен

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Такой код банер не показывает, но если эту хтмлку залить на сервер и вызвать 
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://script_html_adress.html");

То ява скрипт срабатывает. Подскажите что можно сделать , что бы ява скрипты выполнялись локально при помощи команды mWebView.loadData или аналогичных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы скриптов нужно использовать метод loadDataWithBaseURL:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com", nextAd, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: только текст скрипта нужно заменить тогда на такой

"</script>"+
"<script type=\"text/javascript\""+
"src=\"/pagead/show_ads.js\">"+
"</script>"

спасибо.